# Using ExtractValue and XMLType in MAterialized view

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, materialized-views, xmltype

I'm trying to create a materialized view that will present a tabular view on XML data contained in a table. I am also hoping to use the auto refresh option to ensure the MV is always up to date.

Some background:
Oracle 10.2

table def:

```
CREATE TABLE AGREEMENTEXTENSIONDATA (
    AGREEMENTEXTENSIONDATAID  NUMBER(18)          NOT NULL,
    EXTENSIONDATA             NCLOB,  
    AGREEMENTID               NUMBER(18)          NOT NULL)
```

example of extensiondata:

```
<Extensions>
  <ExtensionData id="2" name="IncludePortfolio" type="4">true</ExtensionData>
</Extensions>
```

I have create a log on the table:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON AGREEMENTEXTENSIONDATA
NOCACHE
LOGGING
NOPARALLEL
WITH PRIMARY KEY
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

I am then trying to create the following MV:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_ExtAgreements
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
as
select AGREEMENTEXTENSIONDATAID,
       agreementid,
       extractvalue(xmltype(EXTENSIONDATA), '/Extensions/ExtensionData[@id=''1'']')
from agreementextensiondata
/
```

But get the following message:

```
ORA-30373: object data types are not supported in this context
```

I saw another post suggesting to use a function to extract the values from XML, but this does not work either:

```
create or replace function extractVARCHAR2Extension(p_xml in clob, in_number in VARCHAR2) 
return varchar2 deterministic   
is 
begin  
   return xmltype(p_xml).extract('/Extensions/ExtensionData[@id=''' || in_number ||  ''']/text()').getstringval();
end;
/
```

but the following statement fails:

```
select extractVARCHAR2Extension(extensiondata,'2')
from agreementextensiondata 
    where agreementid = 136
```

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kghsccread1], [128], [0], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 254
ORA-06512: at "ALGOV5.EXTRACTVARCHAR2EXTENSION", line 5
```

??

Any guidance welcome, I maybe using the wrong set of tools here.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change `p_xml in clob` to `p_xml in Nclob`.